# How do I replace the deprecated RmiRegistryFactoryBean in Spring 6?

Tags: spring, registry, rmi

What is the alternative to `RmiRegistryFactoryBean` in Spring 6, since `RmiRegistryFactoryBean` is deprecated?

We have some configs as below

```
<bean id="rmiRegistry" class="org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiRegistryFactoryBean">
        <property name="port" value="8989"/>
</bean>
```